# Passing binary data to a dll function in D7

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-7

Could anyone provide me with working example of passing arbitrary number of bytes 
through the parameter to a dll function?

I would like to do it without any extra memory unit, just only operate on basic windows types.

I need to "send" about 300 kb data per each call.

Should the memory allocated on the client side be free also on the client side?

Comment: we would, but we want to see that you've tried something...

Comment: About allocation and deallocation: Either do both on the caller side or both on the callee side. So if you want to allocate it on the client side free it on the client side as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DLL function should look like this:

```
procedure Test(Buffer: Pointer; Length: Integer); stdcall;
begin
  //Buffer points to the start of the buffer. 
  //The Buffer size if Length bytes.
end;
```

Assuming you are calling it from another Delphi module the call could look like this:

```
procedure Test(Buffer: Pointer; Length: Integer); stdcall; external 'test.dll';

procedure CallTest;
var
  Buffer: array of Byte;
begin
  SetLength(Buffer, 1000);
  //populate Buffer
  Test(@Buffer[0], Length(Buffer));
end;
```

It is always preferable to define an interface which requires memory to be allocated and deallocated in the same module.

The above example allocates and deallocates in the caller's module. This means that the `Test` method would either have to process the `Buffer` completely before returning, or take a copy of the contents of `Buffer` before returning.

Now, whilst it is possible to have the allocation and deallocation in the callee's module, this is less common. It is less common because it is typically less convenient to do it this way. It often entails more API functions, or perhaps more a complex interface. You will be pushed into the route of callee allocation when the caller is not able to determine an appropriate size for the buffer.

When data is being passed from caller to callee than caller allocate is invariably the best choice. When the data flows in the other direction it is more likely that callee allocates would be appropriate.

Comment: You didn't say anything about the deallocation: Since `Buffer` is a dynamic array it will be freed when `CallTest` is left. So the DLL has  to make its own copy if it intends to keep the data around after the `Test` call.

Comment: I think module allocation should be done when you are *returning* a buffer from the module function and then deallocation it in the caller function (e.g `LocalAlloc` in module and `LocalFree` in caller).

Comment: @kobik Generally one strives to avoid callee allocation if at all possible. But yes, there are times when it is the right solution.

Comment: The OP asked to pass "arbitrary bytes", so I would declare the function as taking a `Pointer` parameter instead of a `PByte` parameter.  The function can cast the `Pointer` to `PByte` internally when needed, but this way allows the caller to pass any kind of memory address without having to manually cast it on its end.

Comment: @kobik: if the DLL has to return memory to the caller, it is better to export an extra function from the DLL that allows the DLL to free the memory, since only it knows how the memory was allocated in the first place and thus how to free it properly. The best option is to let the caller allocate memory and pass it to the DLL for filling in the contents as needed. There are advantages and tradeoffs to either model.