# How to convert Pointer back to Array of byte (or a Stream)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a function which creates Pointer to a data from a Stream.

```
function StreamToByteArray(Stream: TStream): Pointer;
var
  ByteArr: array of Byte;
begin
  if Assigned(Stream) then
  begin
    Stream.Position := 0;
    SetLength(ByteArr, Stream.Size);
    Stream.Read(ByteArr[0], Stream.Size);
  end
  else
    SetLength(ByteArr, 0);
  result := @ByteArr[0];
end;
```

How can I convert it back, from a Pointer to dynamic byte array and 
then save the content to a stream. Or maybe it is possible to load stream directly from 
a Pointer?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ouch, this code is (unfortunately) very bad. Your function returns a pointer to the ByteArr array, but unfortunately that array runs out of scope when the function exists: you're essentially returning an Invalid Pointer! Even if the error doesn't immediately pop up, you've got a latent Access Violation in there.

#### Longer explanation

A `Pointer` is a dangerous structure: it doesn't contain data, it simply says where that data exists. Your example of an untyped `Pointer` is the most difficult kind of Pointer, it says *nothing* about the data that exists at the given address. It might point towards some bytes you read from a stream, might point to a string or even a picture of some sorts. You can't even know the amount of data that's at the given address.

The Pointer concept is closely related to the concept of allocating memory. We use many different techniques for allocation memory, using local variables, global variables, objects, dynamic arrays etc. In your sample function you're using a dynamic array, the `array of Byte`. The compiler does a very nice job of shielding you from the internals of allocating and reallocation memory, you can simply use `SetLength()` to say how big the array should be. Things work pretty well because the dynamic array is a *managed* data structure in Delphi: the compiler keeps track of how you're using the dynamic array and will *free* the associated memory as soon as the dynamic array is no longer needed. As far as the compiler is concerned, the associated memory is no longer required when your function exists.

When you're doing:

```
Result := @ByteArr[0];
```

You're essentially taking the address for the compiler-allocated memory block. Since you're using a very low level structure to do that (the `Pointer`), the compiler can't possibly keep track of your usage of the memory, so it will free the memory when the function exists. That leaves you with a Pointer to un-allocated memory.

#### How to properly return a `Pointer` from a function

First of all you should avoid Pointers if possible: they're low-level, the compiler can't help with type-safety or deallocation, they're simply too easy to get wrong. And when you do get Pointers wrong, the errors are usually Access Violations, and they're difficult to track.

That said, if you *really* want to return a pointer, you should return a pointer to explicitly allocated memory, so you know the compiler doesn't free it for you. When you do that, make sure the receiving code knows it's responsible for the memory (should free the memory when it's no longer needed). For example, your function could be re-written like this:

```
function StreamToByteArray(Stream: TStream): Pointer;
begin
  if Assigned(Stream) then
    begin
      Result := AllocMem(Stream.Size);
      Stream.Position := 0;
      Stream.Read(Result^, Stream.Size);
    end
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

#### How to change a Pointer back to `array of byte` or `TStream`

The answer is, there's no way to change it back. A pointer is just that, a pointer to some random data. An array of byte is more then the data it contains. A `TStream` is even more abstract: it's an interface that tells you how to retrieve data, it doesn't necessarily hold any data. For example, a `TFileStream` (and that *is* a `TStream`) doesn't hold *any* bytes of data: all the data is in the file on disk.

Comment: Thanks for first code snippet, but I cannot believe that i can do nothing with a pointer and data Length to convert it back to a Stream or byte array. If I know that it points to the memory, I know the size, and the fact it is a byte array, isn't enough to convert it back?

Comment: You shouldn't convert it back, even if you know it's the first byte of a `array of byte`: Remember the dynamic array is a managed structure, when you're working directly with the in-memory structure, you're essentially messing with it's use-counters (the Compiler doesn't know what you're doing). Even if you could do that *today* and for *your* version of Delphi, that would rely on implementation details that may change in future versions of Delphi. Not to mention there's no type safety when doing that. What's wrong with returning an `array of byte` if that's what you need?

Comment: Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296054/passing-binary-data-to-a-dll-function-in-d7 Just wanted to get the data back in a dll function ...

Comment: That's different from your code: with that code the DLL function is called *before* the `CallTest` procedure returns, so the `array of byte` is valid for the duration of the `Test()` call. The DLL is *not* supposed to keep a copy of the received pointer. If that's what you want to do, it's a good approach; Just make sure you *copy* the data in the DLL if you need to make sure the data stays valid after your DLL function returns.

Comment: Ok but Still I am coming to the problem of making use of the Pointer just for a method's duration in a dll. I have just loaded the arrat of byte in a loop (byte per byte) but it is too slow. So isn't there a faster convertion?

Comment: You might want to consider asking a new question: this one's about `"converting a pointer back to an array of byte"`. I can't answer in comments (because this is not a forum) and I can't change the answer because then it would no longer be the answer to the asked question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7790/discussion-between-user740144-and-cosmin-prund)

Answer (score 3):

If you need a pointer to memory to pass to e.g. a function in a DLL, you should make that call while the buffer is still allocated. There are numerous ways to refactor the code below, but the same principle applies regardless of how your code ends up: You must not pass your pointer around after buffer has already been deallocated.

```
var
  ByteArr: array of Byte;
begin
  if Assigned(Stream) then
  begin
    Stream.Position := 0;
    SetLength(ByteArr, Stream.Size);
    Stream.Read(ByteArr[0], Stream.Size);
  end
  else
    SetLength(ByteArr, 0);
  Test(Pointer(ByteArray),Length(ByteArray));
end;
```

In your Test procedure you can do this:

```
procedure Test(aData: Pointer; aCount: Integer);
var
  ByteArr: array of Byte;
begin
  SetLength(ByteArr,aCount);
  Move(aData^,Pointer(ByteArr)^,aCount);
```

Comment: Yep Now, I know, but the tricky question is how Can I make use of The pointer to load the array of byte back or load it to a Stream?

Comment: Do you mean inside your Test function? Simply allocate a new array of Byte and use Move.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution:

```
type
  TBytes = array of byte;

function StreamToByteArray(Stream: TStream): TBytes;
begin
  if Assigned(Stream) then
  begin
    Stream.Position := 0;
    SetLength(result, Stream.Size);
    Stream.Read(pointer(result)^, Stream.Size);
  end
  else
    SetLength(result, 0);
end;

procedure Test;
var P: pointer;
begin
  P := pointer(StreamToByteArray(aStream)); // returns an allocated TBytes
  // ... use P
end; // here the hidden TBytes will be released
```

You can use `pointer()` around the result to get the memory location.

And your code won't leak any memory nor trigger any access violation, since an implicit try...finally block will be added by the compiler:

```
procedure Test;
var P: pointer;
    tmp: TBytes; // created by the compiler
begin
  tmp := StreamToByteArray(aStream)); // returns an allocated TBytes
  try
    P := pointer(tmp);
    // ... use P
  finally  // here the hidden TBytes will be released
    Finalize(tmp);
  end;
end;
```

You can use `RawByteString` instead of `TBytes` if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Cosmin is right your are returing a pointer to an array that will become out of scope, the pointer will point to an area of memory that was on the stack and may get overwriten, It may appear as though the function works if  you use the resust immediatly.

You need to pass the array to be filled into the function as well, or as I usually do (depending upon the data type) simple return a string and use that as a byte array (if you intend to move to a newer Delphi you need to be careful which string type your use).

Also dynamic arrays store the length and data type before the data (8 bytes of) and passing pointers to the 1st element losses the fact its a dynamic array and becomes just a memory buffer making freeing of the array dangerous.

To answer your question, a pointer (+ length) can be put back into a stream with the TStream.WriteBuffer. You may need to clear the stream first as this, as most stream write operations do, will append from the current stream position.

Hope that helps

Comment: Implementation detail, but: The memory for a Dynamic Array is allocated on the heap, not on the stack.

Comment: @Dampsquid Ok I understand, I have moved the conversion section to the function which need it. however when I do: MemStream.WriteBuffer(Buffer, Length); (where Buffer is a Pointer) I get AV, How can i properly write the buffer content to a stream?

Comment: The problem with this code: MemStream.WriteBuffer(Buffer, Length); (where Buffer is a Pointer) is that the Buffer parameter of WriteBuffer is untyped const and not a pointer. You have to use the standard pascal dereference operator ^ like this: MemStream.WriteBuffer(Buffer^, Length)

Comment: IMHO it won't be possible to call FreeMem() at all supplying the first element pointer of the array. But the trick to return a string is good - you shall better return a `RawByteString` or a `TBytes`, which both can be typecasted to a pointer.